# Problema al crear un proyecto de java web en apache

Tags: java, web, netbeans, apache, java-ee

Hola amigos tengo un problema con la creación de proyectos de java web en apache netbeans 19, el error comienza con la activacion del plugin "Java Web and EE" al intenar activarlo sale mensaje de error *1ra imagen* . Luego al intentar crear un nuevo proyecto de java web aparece la opción de crear pero hay que activar el plugin, el programa trata de instalarlo solo pero sale un error bastante grande *2da imagen* tambien adjunto el mensaje de error de la primer imagen.[image: primer imagen]
[image: 2da imagen]

**Mensaje de error 1ra imagen:**
Activation failed: Cannot enable RichFaces[org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.richfaces] - module org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf/2 > 2.0 SOAP Web Services[org.netbeans.modules.websvc.kit] - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.jaxwsapi > 1.1 - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.clientapi > 1.6 - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.manager > 1.0 - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.jaxwsmodel/1 > 1.2 - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.editor.hints > 1.0 - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.design > 1.0 - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.owsm > 1.0 - module org.netbeans.modules.web.kit > 1.0 - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.core > 1.7 - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.customization > 1.1 PrimeFaces[org.netbeans.modules.web.primefaces] - module org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf/2 > 2.0 - module org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.kit > 1.9 Service Registry[org.netbeans.modules.websvc.saas.kit] - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.saas.codegen > 1.0 - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.saas.api > 1.0 - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.saas.ui > 1.0 ICEfaces[org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.icefaces] - module org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf/2 > 2.0 Struts[org.netbeans.modules.web.struts] - module org.netbeans.modules.web.kit > 1.0 EJB and EAR[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.kit] - module org.netbeans.modules.web.kit > 1.0 - module org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.earproject > 1.7 - module org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.clientproject > 1.1 - module org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ejbjarproject > 1.6 REST HTML5 Client[org.netbeans.modules.web.client.rest] - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.restapi/0-1 > 1.14 - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.rest/0-1 > 1.14 RESTful Web Services[org.netbeans.modules.websvc.restkit] - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.restapi/0 > 1.0 - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.saas.kit > 1.1 - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.kit > 1.1 - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.rest/0 > 1.0 - module org.netbeans.modules.websvc.saas.codegen.j2ee > 1.2 Java EE Base[org.netbeans.modules.web.kit] - module org.netbeans.modules.web.project > 1.6 - module org.netbeans.libs.jstl/1 > 2.31 - module org.netbeans.modules.web.client.rest > 1.0 JSF[org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.kit] - module org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.navigation/1 > 2.0 - module org.netbeans.modules.web.kit > 1.0 - module org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf/2 > 2.0 - module org.netbeans.modules.web.jsf.editor > 1.36 Spring Web MVC[org.netbeans.modules.spring.webmvc] - module org.netbeans.modules.web.kit > 1.0